# Better KEDA Queue Length and AWS SQS Receive Message Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, message-queue, keda

We've created a .net worker that pulls messages from AWS SQS, we've set the max messages to 10 and that means read 10 messages from the queue in one shot. We want the messages to be processed without latency so we are trying to set the queue length as 1 in keda configuration. I see as per the [KEDA documentation](https://keda.sh/docs/2.10/scalers/aws-sqs/)

```
queueLength - Target value for queue length passed to the scaler. Example: if one pod can handle 10 messages, set the queue length target to 10. If the actual messages in the SQS Queue is 30, the scaler scales to 3 pods. (default: 5)
```

Both the queue length and max messages handled by a pod has to match. Is this mandatory? Do we run into issues when we have the queue length as 1 and max messages as 10?

We also thought about reading one message from a queue but that'll increase the no pods. Currently the worker pulls the messages and after processing it only it'll again pull the message from queue. Do we need to do the pulling the messages in another thread and processing in different threads (tasks)?